# Elasticseach query filter/term not working when special characters are involved

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

The following query is not working when "metadata.name" has "-" in the text like "demo-application-child3" . But if I remove "-" and make the query to "demoapplicationchild3". It works. The same with other field metadata.version. I've the data for both demoapplicationchild3 and demo-application-child3. suggestions please.

```
 {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
          {"term": { "metadata.name": "demo-application-child3" }},
          {"term": { "metadata.version": "00.00.100" }}]
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your index mapping as well, please?

Comment: Could you execute the below to add mapping `http://host:port/indexName/_mapping`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

term queries are not analyzed see the [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) which clearly mention this

> Returns documents that contain an exact term in a provided field.

Which clearly means that index time you are using some custom analyzer which is removing `-` and joining the tokens ie for `demo-application-child3` your custom analyzer would be generating `demoapplicationchild3` token, which you can easily confirm using the [Analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

If you want to get result either change `term` query to `match` query or use the `.keyword` suffix with your field if mappping is generated dynamically or create another field which is of type [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) which uses no-op analyzer.